# independence of uniform random variables1

Tags: probability-theory, statistical-inference

let $X_j \sim U(0,1)$

if $$Y_j=\frac{X_j}{X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n}$$

I want to show that:

- $Y_j $are independent
- $\operatorname{Var}(Y_1)=\dfrac{c}{n^2} +o\left(\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)$  then calculate $c$

Comment: But $\sum_{j=1}^n Y_j = 1$. Are you seeking to prove independence of certain subset of $\{Y_j\}_{j=1}^n$?

Comment: @Sasha ,no i want to show the independence of $Y_1 ,Y_2,...,Y_n$

Comment: @yalda The point Sasha is making is that the $Y_i$ are clearly not independent; what you're trying to show is false.

Comment: @JonathanChristensen I don't know why they are not independence!!

Comment: @yalda Consider the case $n=2$. Then $Y_2 = 1-Y_1$: once we know the value of $Y_1$, we also know the value of $Y_2$. They aren't independent for higher $n$, either.

Comment: @JonathanChristensen thanks I understand ,so i want to prove independence of certain subset of  $Y_j$

Comment: @yalda None of the $Y_j$ are independent. If I observe $Y_1 = .2$, that means that $Y_2, \dots, Y_n$ can't be greater than $.8$.

Comment: @JonathanChristensen ,what If the denominatoris is $Y_1+Y_2+...+Y_j$?

Comment: @yalda still not independent. Maybe if you can explain what you're trying to do we can figure out how to do it?

Comment: @JonathanChristensen sorry my mean is If the denominatoris $X_1+X_2+...+X_j$,in my question just only this items mentioned

Comment: I up-voted this question and the vote total is now $0$.  Therefore someone down-voted it.  Could they explain why?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\var}{\operatorname{var}}$
$\newcommand{\cov}{\operatorname{cov}}$

Since $Y_1+\cdots+Y_n$ is constrained to be $1$, we have $\var(Y_1+\cdots+Y_n)=0$.  But
$$
\var(Y_1+\cdots+Y_n)= \var(Y_1)+\cdots+\var(Y_n) + \underbrace{2\cov(Y_1,Y_2)+\cdots}_{\binom n 2 \text{ terms}}
$$
By symmetry, all of the variances are equal to each other and all of the covariances are equal to each other.  Thus you have
$$
n\var + 2\binom n 2 \cov = 0.
$$
Thus
$$
\var = \frac{-2\binom n 2}{n}\cov = \frac{-\cov}{n}.
$$
So it seems $c/n$ rather than $c/n^2$ is what you need.  (And they can't be independent since $\var>0$, so $\cov<0$, and there's still the problem of finding $c$.)